# Почему нельзя сказать, что параметрический полиморфизм основан на динамическом связывании?

Tags: java, c++, ооп

Ведь в этом случае мы так же заранее не знаем типа объекта. Вот из книги:

> Из всех реализованных видов полиморфизма  возможность изменчивости в период вычислений обеспечивает лишь полиморфизм подтипов. Это про C++. В Java так же есть все виды полиморфизмов.

Почему нельзя сказать, что параметрический полиморфизм основан на динамическом связывании?

Comment: так в c++ при компиляции для каждого сочетания типов из шаблона генерируется отдельный класс/функция, а в java информация о параметризации стирается.

Comment: не особо проясняет этот ответ картину для меня..